# kernal panic not syncing: VFS unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel

I upgraded from 15.04 to 15.10 and received some system errors.
Reinstalled 15.10 without checking the format box -- so all user files untouched
Now receive "end kernel panic not syncing: VFS unable to mount root fs on unknown block(0,0)".
There are two other Ubuntu 14.04 on same disk.  I am using one of them now.
Ran bootinfoscript.  Not sure how to interpret RESULTS.txt file from bootinforscript output.  Need guidance on what to do.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Installing to a partition that has Linux without formatting is never a good idea, there are probably leftover config files from the previous install causing problems.  Your best bet is to copy any important files off, reformat, and reinstall Ubuntu.